# How can I get UINavigationbar items to show when the view is pushed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, navbar

In my appdelagate I have this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

I have a masterview and detailview, masterview is a table, when I click a row in masterview is pushes to detailview, but the barbutton items I've added to detailview won't show up. It looks like this:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you show us how you've added the bar button items?

Comment: You say "the barbutton items I've added to detailview won't show up". What code do you use to add them?

Comment: thinking of the obvious, but: ensure they're not hidden in ib; is there any logic in your controller that manipulates the toolbar or it's buttons, and if so, are those elements wired up properly in the xib/storyboard? I'd think some simple debug within viewWillAppear would provide some clues

Answer (score 0):

I am going to offer an alternative to what you are doing because I am not sure why your items are not showing. My guess is that the navigation bar in **detailViewController** is being covered by a clean copy of it after you push the view controller.

In the `-viewDidLoad()` method, in **detailViewController.m** add UIBarButtonItem manually.

// create a standard save button

    `UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]`

```
              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
              target:self
              action:@selector(saveAction:)];

saveButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;  
[buttons addObject:saveButton];  
[saveButton release];
```